# Can K-Means cluster label be fixed

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning

Is there any way to fix the K-Means cluster label.  I am working with 4 clusters and whenever I run the python program from the beginning the cluster labels change. Is it possible to fix the cluster labels. I am trying to play with the parameter random state, but does not seem to work.

Comment: It should work with `random_state=c`. Please share the snippet.

Comment: I have random state to be 1, it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

It's working for me with `random_state`

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
x, y = load_digits(return_X_y=True)
x = (x - x.mean())/x.std()

def create_cluster(k = 2, random_state=0):
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k, random_state=random_state)
    kmeans.fit(x)
    return kmeans

y_pred = create_cluster(k=25).predict(x)
y_pred_2 = create_cluster(k=25, random_state=0).predict(x)
all(y_pred==y_pred_2) # True

y_pred_2 = create_cluster(k=25, random_state=1).predict(x)
all(y_pred==y_pred_2) # False
```

Answer (score 0):

Different solutions are likely caused by random initialisation since K-means finds a local optimum (once running, it is deterministic). Fix the random seed for all packages used, e.g. numpy, tensorflow (if you're doing this, maybe you're not doing it for all packages?)

Comment: I am using Python and Numpy. But I have a dataset of  shape (50K, 3).

Comment: @GabS perhaps edit the question to specify what you're using (packages etc) and/or a code snippet as in 10xAI's answer